# Scan barcode in TextField as one string

Tags: flutter, dart, barcode-scanner

When paste barcode string in TextField in log I have one line
eg. **[log] 28333242917284**

But when scan barcode with android device (device for listing goods) in console get:

```
[log] 2
[log] 28
[log] 283
[log] 2833
[log] 28333
[log] 283332
[log] 2833324
[log] 28333242
[log] 283332429
[log] 2833324291
[log] 28333242917
[log] 283332429172
[log] 2833324291728
[log] 28333242917284
```

Is it possible get one line same as "**on paste**"?

```
TextField(
   autofocus: false,
   cursorColor: Colors.black,
   controller: controllerItems,
   onChanged: onSearchTextChangedItems,
)  

onSearchTextChangedItems(String text) async {

    log(text);
........
```

Comment: What barcode scanning package are you using?

Comment: @Wh1t3rabbit   I don't use any package, On android device I have orange button when press in textField I get barcode.

Answer (score 0):

I'm change **TextField**  to **TextFormField**  and

**onChanged** to **onFieldSubmitted** now work fine.

```
TextFormField(
   autofocus: false,
   cursorColor: Colors.black,
   controller: controllerItems,
   onFieldSubmitted: onSearchTextChangedItems,
)
```